# Selecting objects from a grouped linq query

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of objects that I group with a L2O linq query.

The results of that query are as follows:

[image: L2O query objects]

Now, I want to transform this query into a query that returns **the highest number of each key.**

The only thing I got until now is the following:

```
var orderStuff = from i in collection
                 group i by i.Letter;
```

But I am having a real hard time to expand on this.

Comment: you mean it only returns like  A an 4 for each item

Comment: Yeah, so A = 4, B = 4, C = 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns a set of `IGrouping<String, int>`.  This type has a `Key` property with the group's label, and inherits `IEnumerable<int>` containing the items in the group.

You want to select the `Max()` of each group.

For example:

```
var orderStuff = from i in collection
                 group i by i.Letter into g
                 select new { Letter = g.Key, Max = g.Max() };
```

Comment: Right, I get this. But is it possible to return the objects themselves instead of defining a new anonymous type? And I don't mean select new MyType { ... } , but really get the object that is contained in the enumeration that is the result of the query?

Comment: @The: I'm not sure what you mean.  You might want to `OrderByDescending(...).First()`.

Comment: Well, the query I put in my post groups objects by a certain letter. Instead of doing select new {} or select new MyType {} I just want to get the object out of the grouped result. Because if you iterate over the query with a foreach, you would get the objects per key.

So maybe something like this:

(outer query) Get object with highest value from each key in
(inner query) group objects by Letter

Comment: @The: You do want something like `select g.OrderByDescending(...).First()`